# Injured boy overhears mutiny plot on space station

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

So in the 6th grade or so I read a short story,  and I really loved it,  and now I have no idea what it's called but I want to enjoy it again. 
I remember that there was a young boy, around 14(?) years of age on board a spaceship or space station. He gets injured (his arm?) at some point early on in the story,

While in the infirmary and under some sedation,  he overhears a mutiny plot by two men. The two men later proceed with their plan,  and the other men get locked in the cabins. The boy then has to crawl through a garbage chute while holding a canister of something (it could break and hurt him but I don't remember what's in it).

He makes it and saves the ship.  Maybe be using gas to take out the mutineers,  or he blew open the door to the other men's room with a bomb,  I'm not sure.

It also had pictures to go along with it.

Comment: If you described the boy overhearing the mutiny plots from inside a barrel of apples instead of sedated in the infirmary I would answer you "Treasure Island" by R. L. Stevenson. ;)

Comment: **You might also want to use a more descriptive question title**.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the *Treasure Island* idea mentioned by Ginasius, maybe it's Charles Sheffield's [*Godspeed.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DYURLM8)

from the Amazon link:

> Jay Hara is an ordinary young man growing up on the isolated planet of Erin. But Jay dreams of adventure and escapades and the legend of the lost “Godspeed” drive which allowed humans to travel at faster-than-light speeds.
>      His life changes when he joins up with the seedy spacer, Paddy Enderton and Captain Daniel Shaker. Captain Shaker is a charming but ruthless adventurer who inspires both fear and admiration in equal measure, and he and his questionable crew are joined by Jay as they race to find the legendary drive Jay Hara used to dream about.
>      Godspeed is a true coming-of-age tale told in the classic tradition of R.L. Stevenson’s Treasure Island. A modern day pirate story, set among the stars.

[image]

Comment: I was in the sixth grade 6 years ago

Comment: I'm afraid it's neither of the two mentioned so far,  but thank you!